# Passing a value from HTML to component in angular with Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code shows correctly all the documents from Firestore collection **doctors.**

```
this.db
      .collection("doctors")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.Doctors = res.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Doctor
          }
        })
      });
```

in HTML I display the data in this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let doctor of Doctors">
      <div class="list-group">
        <h5 class="mb-2">{{ doctor.doctorID }}</h5>
        <p class="mb-2"> {{ doctor.category }}</p>
        <p class="mb-2"> {{ doctor.doctorName }} </p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="getDoctorReviews(doctorID)">Show Reviews</button>
          <button class='btn btn-secondary' (click)="hideDoctorReviews()">Hide</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need a way to pass the **value** of **doctorID** to **component.ts** when **I click** the button **Show Reviews**. Now I in component.ts I receive that doctorID is undefined.

[image: button Show Reviews]
I need this value to make a filter on the reviews collection.

```
this.db
  .collection("reviews", ref => ref.where("doctorID", "==", doctorID))
```

```js
//doctor Class
export class Doctor {
    doctorID: string;
    category: string;
    doctorName: string;
    reviewsNumber: number;
    
  }
  
//review Class
export class Review {
    doctorID: string;
    doctorName: string;
    userID: string;
    userName: String;
    rating: string;
    message: string;
    
}
//component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  Doctors: Doctor[];
  Reviews: Review[]; 
  doctorID : string;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.db
      .collection("doctors")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.Doctors = res.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Doctor
          }
        })
      });
  }

  showReviews: boolean = false;

  getDoctorReviews() {
    this.showReviews = true;
    
    this.db
      .collection("reviews", ref => ref.where("doctorID", "==", doctorID))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.Reviews = res.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Review
          }
        })
      });
  }

  hideDoctorReviews() {
    this.showReviews = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let doctor of Doctors">
  <div class="list-group">
    <h5 class="mb-2">{{ doctor.doctorID }}</h5>
    <p class="mb-2"> {{ doctor.category }}</p>
    <p class="mb-2"> {{ doctor.doctorName }} </p>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="getDoctorReviews(doctorID)">Show Reviews</button>
      <button class='btn btn-secondary' (click)="hideDoctorReviews()">Hide</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I **appreciate** any suggestion(s).

Comment: You need to send the `doctorID` of the `doctor` object. Try: `getDoctorReviews(doctor.doctorID)`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify `doctorId` to `doctor.doctorId`.

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="getDoctorReviews(doctor.doctorID)">Show Reviews</button>
```

And you have to add argument `doctorId` in your `ts` file.

```
getDoctorReviews(doctorId: string) {
    :
```

Comment: This issue blocked me for more than one week. Now after so many days I can continue with my project. Thank you so much!